# swift Xcode unit test: Cannot convert value of type "Person" to expected argument type "Person"

Tags: xcode, swift, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test class to test my custom classes. When I am trying to call a method in the custom class with a custom object as the input variable, I got:
'Cannot convert value of type "Person"  to expected argument type "Person". "Person" is the class, inherited from NSManagedObject, where the input object was created from. I have no problem with other methods taking other value type. The method works fine. The test class is the only one complains this. Is it a bug or limitation? Any suggestion I can dig deeper on this issue?

Comment: Could be a namespace issue. In your Core Data model, when you select the Person entity, do you have a module name specified in the Identity inspector? This might have the form <yourtarget>.Person. If so, try removing it and leaving it blank.

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured it. In the test class, the object was not created correctly like it was in normal. I was misled by the error message.

Answer (score 8):

I was running into this issue earlier. It turns out that the system under test (in my case it was a service calling the object; a PersonService for your example, perhaps) did not have Target membership to the test project. I just clicked the .swift file, and made sure both the main project and test project were checked.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank. I will also check that.

Comment: In my case, the issue was that the object in question had target membership in both a framework and a service. However, it only needed the target membership in the framework because the service imported the framework.

Comment: @Andrew thanks!  That's what it was for me.  I had my main project target files also targeting my tests and was importing them with "@testable".  The main project files should only be targeting the main project and vice-versa.

Comment: @Andrew You saved my life, could you please answer my most recent post with this answer again?