# Swift 3 Unit Test throws compile error "Cannot convert value 'Type' to 'Type'"

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, xctest, initialization

I have a struct (partial)

```
struct Event : JSONSerializable, Glossy {
    let name : String
    let start : String
    private var startTimeZone: String
    let finish : String
    private var finishTimeZone: String
```

that when called from UnitTest:

```
func testReal() {
    let event : Event = Event()
    let editor = EventEditor(forEvent: Event())
    XCTAssertNotNil(editor)
}
```

throws compile error:
    Cannot convert value of type 'Event' to expected arguement type 'Event'

EventEditor is:

```
import Foundation

class EventEditor {
let event : Event

   init(forEvent event: Event) {
        self.event = event
    }
}
```

But if when called from product (aka outside if unit tests) it works just fine with no errors or issues.
JSONSerializable -- helper extensions to convert to/from JSON
Glossy -- cocoapod for json parsing.

I've tried created a stripped down version of Event and adding pieces (eg  JSONSerializable, Glossy)

Can anyone suggest why this wouldn't work in XCTest but works in other code?

Comment: do you have `@testable import nameOfYourProject` under `Import XCTest`?

Comment: isn't this line: `let event : Event = Event()` giving you an error? You are **not** giving it any value to its parameters, you should initialize with `Event(name: "John", start: " May 1st", ...)` OR your struct could have default values as in `let name : String = "" let start : String = "Jan 1st" ,...` give all the properties of struct a default value so you can do `Event()` which would basically initialize to the default values

Comment: also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419707/cannot-convert-value-of-type-x-to-expected-argument-type-x)

Answer (score 6):

Very possibly you have added the file that contains the `Event` struct to both your main target and your test target.

To check if this is the case, select the file in the Project navigator, then show the Utilities pane on the right, and check the Target Membership. If your test target is checked, uncheck it.

In your XCTest file, add `@testable import YourMainTargetNameHere` to the top of the file.

Comment: Crazy enough that's the reason, he should accept this answer because its the correct one.

Comment: Perfect, Mike! In my case, I added some files to the test target (which you shouldn't do, obviously just use `@testable import X`). Going to your 'Compile Sources' build phase and looking through the files should help find the cause.