# Unit tests not compiling - Swift Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing, tdd

I am learning some TDD for Swift and I came across an issue that Xcode wont compile my test code. I have no clue what could be wrong with this.

Other tests are working fine (also tests for "ListItem" and "Location"). I also closed Xcode many times and cleared Derived Data and even the project itself.

Below the screenshots of code and compile error. If I change the "ListItem" parameter in the method to "Any" (and change the type of the array also), it is compiling. But this is not the code I want without the specific type.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here: [swift Xcode unit test: Cannot convert value of type "Person" to expected argument type "Person"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250398/swift-xcode-unit-test-cannot-convert-value-of-type-person-to-expected-argumen)

Seems that the ItemManager .swift file was not added to the test target of the project (derp)..